# Parse query not working ( Parse.com)

Tags: parse-platform

I am trying to query custom user table in Parse

```
public async void getData()
{
    int count = 0;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("User");
    query.WhereEqualTo ("username", "J");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> objs = await query.FindAsync();
    foreach (ParseObject obj in objs) 
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

I hardcoded values to check the outcome.Below is the outcome :(

[image]

Below is my Parse table

[image]

Kindly help me identifying the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a long struggle found the answer.

If whereEqualTo condition is added as a next statement it returns all the rows from the table. Else if it is added as below, it returns the matching row alone.

```
public async void getData()
{
    int count = 0;
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("User").WhereEqualTo ("username", "J");
    IEnumerable<ParseObject> objs = await query.FindAsync();
    foreach (ParseObject obj in objs) 
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Count = 1, that is matching rows. Dont know why it works like this .

Comment: code from github
 
 public ParseQuery<T> WhereEqualTo(string key, object value) {
      return new ParseQuery<T>(this, where: new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {key, value}
      });
    }
 
 
 it creates a new request